# Clicking on a hyper link to download excel file (Selenium Via Python)

Tags: python, html, selenium

I want to be able to click on the hyper link to download a CSV file.

HTML code:

```
<a class="dxbButton_Office2010Blue XafFileDataAnchor dxbButtonSys" id="Dialog_v7_15797720_MainLayoutView_xaf_l104_xaf_dviFile_View_HA"href="javascript:;"
```

Selectors Hub:

```
(//span[contains(text(),'Attachment_Stat')])[2]

//a[@id='Dialog_v14_10076318_MainLayoutView_xaf_l491_xaf_dviFile_View_HA']//span[contains(text(),'Attachment_Stat')]
```

I tried the below with no success:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[contains(@text,'Attachment_Stat')]").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

The below worked for me:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(@id,'xaf_dviFile_View_HA')]").click()
```

Comment: I suggest you to accept your answer so that the question gets "closed"

Comment: i can't accept my answer as am new and not allowed to.